# Connect SQL developer with MYSQL server running on Docker container in EC2

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ec2

Could you please guide me How can I connect my local SQL developer to MY SQL Server running on Docker container in EC2. But I havent installed mysql in my ec2 host.

I have tried with public dns and port 3306 but getting below error

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:
```

`Long Message:
Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 353 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 339 milliseconds ago.

Details:
   Type: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
   SQL State: 08S01`

Comment: 2 things you need to check.. 1) Is your port 3306 open to the public or for your private IP? 2) Are you spinning up the docker container by mapping container port to host ie. using -p 3306:3306?

Answer (score 0):

follow the guide in this official AWS documentation

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Use port 3306 however, this is a guide for webservers